# PreBuildEvent and project dependencies in MSBuild

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, projects-and-solutions

I'm having a tricky MSBuild issue.  There is a solution file containing multiple web sites.  Each web site needs a copy of MVC views and other web site content from a common project.  That common project copies files from a shared organizational space.  Here's an illustration:

```
                          Site A
  OrgShared <- Common <-  Site B
                          Site C
```

File copies are performed through the PreBuildEvent of the `.csproj` files.  The problem is that the PreBuildEvent commands run before detected dependencies' build events are fired.  So here's the sequence of events:

```
1. Site A is build
   a. Prebuild step is executed (copy files from Common)
   b. Common is built
      i. Prebuild step is executed (copy files from OrgShared)
      ii. Build & postbuild is executed
   c. Build & postbuild are executed
2. Site B is built
   a. Prebuild step is executed (copy files from Common)
   b. Build & postbuild are executed
```

The problem occurs at step 1a.  Because the Common prebuild step has not yet executed, Site A does not receive the files that indirectly come from OrgShared.

How can I effectively resolve this dependency issue without relying on sites A, B & C having to copy directly from OrgShared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  The reason why Site A was being built before Common was because of the ordering in the `.sln` file.  After changing the ordering in the solution, I was able to have the PreBuildEvent run in Common first.

Before:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Site A", "SiteA.csproj", "{6E7FAE47-74A6-4740-9AC5-9599E850E834}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Common", "Common.csproj", "{C510B337-7459-4494-BBCB-B79FECD2AA66}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Site B", "SiteB.csproj", "{F3CAFCE9-A96D-4EE5-BE09-420E27344345}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Site C", "SiteC.csproj", "{A50C5DE2-4846-40F2-86B1-B103F413DE0F}"
EndProject
```

After:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Common", "Common.csproj", "{C510B337-7459-4494-BBCB-B79FECD2AA66}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Site A", "SiteA.csproj", "{6E7FAE47-74A6-4740-9AC5-9599E850E834}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Site B", "SiteB.csproj", "{F3CAFCE9-A96D-4EE5-BE09-420E27344345}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Site C", "SiteC.csproj", "{A50C5DE2-4846-40F2-86B1-B103F413DE0F}"
EndProject
```